# session variable becomes nil after paypal redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using PAYAPAL payment  type in my application where I am storing the user's product id in a session. But the session variable is getting lost when the page is redirected back to my application from PAYPAL website, any suggestion will be really appreciated.

Comment: I suspect you've a POST request from paypal and you didn't disable the forgery protection for the specific action

Answer (score 2):

According to my experience, the problem is with url you are using, let me explain
Case 1

1. sapose i am log in in the url caled https://myurl.com
2. I amredirected from the paypal to the url https://www.myurl.com

Case 2

1. sapose i am log in in the url caled https://www.myurl.com
2. I amredirected from the paypal to the url https://myurl.com

In this both cases i will lose my session

Reason:

Both https://myurl.com and https://www.myurl.com will take different sessions

To fix this problem either you can write a before filter to alweys redirect to non www url

(OR)

give domain in name .myurl.com in your session.rb initialization file.